# I can't connect to SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I just installed Microsoft SQL 2019, and when I try to connect it says :

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to DESKTOP-GMO8T**.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

The network path was not found
```

[THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWWn8.png)

I also added it in "Allow apps to communicate through [Windows Defender Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC5CE.png) " but still the same.

Anyone knows how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The short answer is that it could be any number of things. That error just means your client can't connect to the server. This could be because the server/service is down, because there is a firewall blocking, etc... and those are just a couple of the potential problems. The duplicate marked at the top of your post has many answers troubleshooting steps to diagnose the issue and steps to fix. Best of luck!

Comment: I added SQL Browser Service EXE and SQL Server Windows NT -64 bit in Windows Defender Firewall. But i still get the same error